# Testing with Generics

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics

I can't seem to find the right scenario for what I'm trying to do despite significant google-ing. I'm new to testing/unit testing/tdd, etc.

I have the following class;

```
public class AssetManager
{
    public DisconnectedBindingList<Change, AssetContext> ChangeList {get; private set;}

    public AssetManager()
    {
        ChangeList = new DisconnectedBindingList<Change, AssetContext>();
    }

    public bool IsChangeValid(Change newChange)
    {
        return ChangeList.Any(c => c.idChange == newChange.idChange);
    }
}
```

To make it more test friendly, I've changed to an Interface;

```
public interface IAssetManager<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    DisconnectedBindingList<Change, TContext> ChangeList {get; set;}

    bool IsChangeValid(Change newChange);
}

public class AssetManager<TContext> : IAssetManager<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{ ... }
```

Obviously there's some 
`DisconnectedBindingList<T,TContext>` is essentially a local cache. `TContext` is only needed during initialization/refresh, which is why it's not passed/stored in the `DisconnectedBindingList`.

This still doesn't really help me with testing though.

I have my test setup as follows;

```
DisconnectedBindingList<Change, TestContext> data = ...
Mock<IAssetManager<TestContext>> mockRepo = new Mock<IAssetManager<TestContext>>();
mockRepo.SetupGet(x => x.ChangeList).Returns(data);
Assert.IsTrue(mockRepo.Object.IsChangeValid(new Change{idChange = 2}));
```

Where `TestContext` is just;

```
public class TestContext : DbContext {}
```

I'm just not quite sure where it's all falling down. Seems like the `AssetManager.IsChangeValid()` method is not being called, which makes sense, since I'm not initializing an AssetManager, only an IAssetManager. I'm lost as to how to re-arrange/refactor the code to get this working though.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing `AssetManager`, so it's probably not a good idea to mock it. 
You want to mock things that *AssetManager depends on*, not AssetManager itself.

Write your test like this:

```
DisconnectedBindingList<Change, TestContext> data = ...
var am = new AssetManager();
am.ChangeList = data;
Assert.IsTrue(am.IsChangeValid(new Change{idChange = 2}));
```

If AssetManager depends on something (say, for example, it reads from the database), you want to mock *that* component out for this test.

Comment: Yeah, ChangeList is private set though, so while I do understand what you're getting at, it doesn't quite work in this case.

Comment: @FizzBuzz In this case, you need to change how it's grabbing data. Either allow it as a constructor argument, or mock out the component which is giving you the data. (For example, if `ChangeList` comes from the database, mock out the database service, and make it return `data` instead)

Comment: Alternatively, you could potentially call `.ChangeList.Clear();` and `ChangeList.AddRange(data);`, assuming the collection allows that (I'm not familiar with `DisconnectedBindingList<,>`)

Comment: Yeah, that's a point. It's basically a BindingList and it's not marked readonly, so I could a clear/add. Is it OK to run the tests like that? I guess I'm testing IsChangeValid, not the database query, so it seems reasonable to do that.

Comment: It's perfectly fine, I think. Your test is testing `IsChangeValid`, and tests should be independent of each other, so completely erasing what the data "should" and replacing it with what you're actually testing is perfectly valid.